# How to import excel to sql server with some column values transforming into row using asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, excel, upload, sql-server-2012

I want to import an excel file to sql server using asp.net with C#.

The user upload the file from the web page by using file upload control.

here is the code.

here I used outer apply to transform columns to row.

when I run the code the below error coming.

IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005).

```
    protected void BtnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string excelPath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

        FileUpload1.SaveAs(excelPath);

        string conString = string.Empty;

        string extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

        switch (extension)
        {
            case ".xls": //Excel 97-03

                conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;

                break;

            case ".xlsx": //Excel 07 or higher

                conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07+ConString"].ConnectionString;

                break;
        }

        conString = string.Format(conString, excelPath);

        using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
        {

            excel_con.Open();

            string sheet1 = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

            DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();                

     string st = “Select [sno], [Id],[country],[Qtr]=case(substring([Qtr],1,2) as nvarchar(4)), [value]  from [“+sheet1+”] outer apply(values((N'Q1',Q1),(N'Q2',Q2)) P(Qtr,value)”;  

 using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(st, excel_con))

            {
                oda.Fill(dtExcelData);
            }

            excel_con.Close();

            string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
            {

                using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
                {

                    //Set the database table name

                    sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "[dbo].[exceldemo]";

                    con.Open();

                    sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData);

                    con.Close();

                    lblUpload.Text = "Uploaded Succesfully";

                }
```

Below is the format. Please check it.

http://i61.tinypic.com/217pk0.jpg

I have also tried with UNPIVOT also.

Please tell me if any thing wrong in the above code and give suggestions to overcome this problem.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to be more precise on what you want to achieve. Are you working in C# or VB.Net? Will the user upload the file from the web page? What have you tried so far?

One way to import an Excel file to SQL Server using ASP.NET is to upload the file to your server with a FileUpload. The user will then be able to choose the file he wants to import.

Then, you will want to read the data in that Excel file and put it in a Datatable. It will enable you to work with it in your code behind. Here is a good example on how to read the data from the Excel file ( http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/509179/Read-Excel-File-into-DataSet-in-ASP-NET-Using-Csha). It is similar to reading that of a database, but you connect to your Excel file.

Now that your data is in the datatable, you will be able to do the manipulations that you want.

Afterwards, you can write your data to your SQL Server in many different ways, it depends on how you write to your database. ADO, NHibernate, EF, Stored Procedures, Dynamic SQL? You can also do a BulkCopy. It will copy all the data from your datatable into the database without having the need to iterate through all the rows of your datatable. You will need to map your columns and make sure your datatable is formatted correctly. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x(v=vs.110).aspx)

Please update your question with more information and what you have tried so far so we can give you a more specific answer.

Comment: Hi Fynnen, thanks for helping. I have updated the question with output format (image link), please check it once.